# JQuery doesn't work trying to "display: block" on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have this simple code here to make a div visible (from display:none; to display:block;)

I've tested this in JSFiddle and it works, but not in my localhost. I think it's something from the script tags.

I can see the css and js files with F12 on my Localhost wamp server, but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/up.js"></script>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="scroll_top">Hello World</div>
  <div class="container">
   <?php include("includes/header.php");?>
   <div class="content">
    <?php include("includes/navigation.php");?>
     <div class="main_content">
     </div>
    </div>
    <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#scroll_top{
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

JS:

```
var $logo = $('#scroll_top');
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $logo.css({display: $(this).scrollTop() > 100? "block":"none"});
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle by Roko C. Buljan, with position fixed and working.
http://jsfiddle.net/psvn9/400/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t67ab/1/)

```
var $logo = $('#scroll_top');
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop()> 100)
        {   //alert("scop");
     //  $logo.css({display: $(this).scrollTop() > 100? "block":"none"});
         $('#scroll_top').css("display", "block");
        }else{
             $('#scroll_top').css("display", "none");
        }

    });
```